# How add a class to a label element with Symfony forms?

Tags: symfony-forms, symfony-3.3

I have a `FormBuilder`with **Symfony3** and I need you to `add` a `class` to the *discount* `label`.
How can you observe the third parameter of the `add` method is an `array` and a key is `attr` which has another `array` with the `attributes` of the `input` element, but not the label.

How can I add `class` to the `label`?

```
 $builder
->add('note', TextareaType::class, array(
    'label' => "Notes",
    'required' => false
))
->add('discount', NumberType::class, array(
    'required' => false,
    'attr' => array(
        'class' => "hidden"
    )
))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see the `label_attr` parameter in [symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/number.html#label-attr)

`'label'=>"Notes,array('label_attr' => array('class' => 'class_name'))"`

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me in Symfony 5.4 : `'label_attr' => ['class' => 'your-label-classes']`

---

### Example:

```
class YourFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
       $builder
            ->add('email', EmailType::class, [
                'label'=>'Your label name',
                'label_attr' => ['class' => 'your-label-classes', 'for'=>"email"],
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => "your-field-classes",
                    'type' => "email",
                ],
            ])
            ...
    }
    ...
}
```